# How do I make a texture sheet with multiple textures for unwraps?

Tags: gimp, 3d, texture

[image]
Can anyone point in in the right direction as to where I could learn how to make an image like this within gimp? I'm honestly in the dark as to what to even call it. I've searched texture map, uv map, and even texture atlas. I'm new to photo manipulation software and would really like to be able to texture my 3d models in this manner. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in GIMP.

1. Put all the texture images in one folder, on your computer, where you can easily find them.
2. In GIMP, click *File > New*, and create a new document the size you need.
3. Click *File > Open As Layers*
4. Navigate to the folder where you stored the images. Select them all and hit OK.

In GIMP all the images will then be imported as layers. That means each image is on a separate layer, and each can be adjusted or repositioned as required.

5. You can move the images with the Move tool.
6. You can scale them with the Scale tool.
7. When you have finished, click *File > Export As*, give the file a name, and choose the file format you want to export to.

Note: If you want to save the image with all the layers still editable for future use, click File > Save As, and save the XCF file.  If you need to edit in future, you use that file. All the layers will still be present, so you can easily move them or rescale them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you can make 3D models and you can decide what you need to the image that you are going to wrap around your model(=textures, their forms, sizes, placements, and positions)

If that's true, you know quite much of things. Making the image is possible in any multilayer image manipulation program. Place your textures to different layers. Then you can separately move, scale, crop, clip and rotate them. Also color, brightness and contrast adjustments are independent for different layers. Finally make your final single layer image or images by exporting as JPG other needed format.

GIMP of course has very large selection of tools and possiblities, but starting with it is a nightmare for a beginner due the sheer number of available options. Practice at first with a simpler program such as Paint.NET.

The following image is an elementary four layer composition in Paint.NET

[image]

The textures were copied and pasted to different layers. GIMP has better tools for clipping if you need non-rectangular areas.

**ADD:** You do not find easily GIMP or other 2D image manipulation software tutorials which are named "texture maps for 3D models or something like that" because 2D image manipulation software  is intended for 2D images. The software itself cannot have a slightest idea that you are going to use your 2D image to be wrapped on a 3D model.

Paint.NET tutorials and documentation are good in showing what is possible and how. It's up to you to see or calculate and actually compose the needed image that can be wrapped onto a surface. Obviously you get the shape outlines for clipping from your 3D program if it's that advanced.

Comment: Sooo. Is there a place where I can learn this or.....

Comment: @Tink3rballz1980 Search for Paint.NET documentation and tutorials. An example: https://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/WorkingWithLayers.html

Comment: It's worth pointing out in terms of order of operations that the UV unwrap portion of this workflow *normally* starts in the 3D app: you create the 3D asset, and then typically you set up the UVs there, and export out either the UVs as a template to open in your 2D app, or export initial prototype textures you assign or create in your 3D app which you then edit in your 2D app.

Also worth pointing out that it's getting more and more common now for folks to texture not in a straight 2D app, but to paint textures live in 3D using tools like Mari, Substance Painter and others.